# code to play sound programmatically using a button on the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I am trying to figure out how to hook up a button to play a sound programmatically without using IB.  I have the code to play the sound, but have no way of hooking the button up to play the sound? any help?

here is my code that I'm using:

```
     - (void)playSound
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boing_1" ofType:@"wav"];
        AVAudioPlayer* myAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                 initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path error:NULL]];
        myAudio.delegate = self;
        myAudio.volume = 2.0;
        myAudio.numberOfLoops = 1;
        [myAudio play];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(playSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

UIButton inherits its target/action methods from [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: this is what i was looking for...i believe i've seen something like this before but couldn't remember where....this should work very well!

Answer (score 0):

To hook up the button, make your `playSound` method the handler for the button's `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event. Assuming this is in a view controller, you might want to put this in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(playSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

FYI, you're leaking memory because you're `alloc`-ing an object but never `release`-ing it.

You should create a new `AVAudioPlayer` member for the class to avoid this.

```
@interface MyViewController : ...
{
    ...
    AVAudioPlayer* myAudio;
    ...
}

- (void)playSound
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boing_1" ofType:@"wav"];
    [myAudio release];
    myAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path error:NULL]];
    myAudio.delegate = self;
    myAudio.volume = 2.0;
    myAudio.numberOfLoops = 1;
    [myAudio play];
}
```

Don't forget to put `[myAudio release]` in your `dealloc` method.

(I did this without declaring `myAudio` as a `@property`, but that's not strictly necessary)

Comment: He probably shouldn't allocate a new instance of AVAudioPlayer every time the method is called. Do something like `if (!myAudio) { myAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path error:NULL]]; }`

Comment: Valid comment, although I think the idea should be "get it working" at first. :)